# Azure Dev Ops API list of results of TC

Tags: api, azure-devops, testcase

I try to get all results of a TestCase via API. In the UI I see a list of all results of a TC via the following url:

**https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyyy/_testPlans/_results?testCaseId=48587**

How can I do this via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this via API?

I am afraid that you couldn't find this API in Official document.

But you could get the API in Browser console:

[image]

Here are the API and Request Body:

API URL:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?excludeUrls=true&enumsAsNumbers=true&msDateFormat=true&noArrayWrap=true&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "contributionIds":["ms.vss-test-web.testcase-results-data-provider"],
    "dataProviderContext":
        {"properties":
            {
                "testCaseId":testcaseid,
                "sourcePage":{"url":"https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_testPlans/execute?planId={TestPlanId}&suiteId={Test SuiteID}","routeId":"ms.vss-test-web.testplans-hub-refresh-route","routeValues":{"project":"{ProjectName}","pivots":"execute","controller":"ContributedPage","action":"Execute"}}
            }
        }

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to get detailed info, you could pass the Test Run id and test result ID to  Rest API: [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)